# Replace 140mm fork with 160mm on Remedy 7 27.5 possible?

Tags: fork, replacement

I'm Curious about whether it's possible or whether Remedy's frame is designed  for such a replacement. Some bicycles makes it possible to upgrade to longer forks. I searched in Google, some people say that it's bicycle dependent. So, who knows about it, can I do this with Remedy or it just doesn't matter?

Comment: 140 to 160 is going to change the geometry quite a bit.  Is this a case of you have a free 160mm or are you thinking about buying one?

Comment: You could in theory put in a new fork provided you matched up all the parameters in selecting a fork, but you would change the geometry.

Comment: Why would you like to change the travel? 140mm is considered long travel on 27.5 trail bike, if you are thinking of turning it into a more gravity focused bike there are probably other more important considerations you will also have to make. Personally I think you'd struggle to realise any advantage with the change. The biggest downside is that your likely to void the warranty if you move to a longer travel fork, which is quite important on a 2014 trail bike. If you want to upgrade the fork there are other options to reduce travel on a fork back to the specified size and retain the warranty.

Comment: To answer your question though, yes you could do it, it's a strong frame. I'd personally consider the Slash if you wanted to go bigger. The Remedy is great at what it's built for, buzzword specific riding and tech trail, but the Slash is designed to go bigger and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I have put 140mm-100mm adjustable forks on an XC bike designed for 100m forks. Going from 140mm to 160mm will change the geometry of the bike a bit, but a bike that already has a 140mm fork is pretty slack to begin with.

Depending on the exact fork and how much you set up the sag, there may be little to no measurable difference between the two forks during "normal" riding. The slacker the head angle, the less difference a change in fork length makes. If you're planning on running it at "All mountain" sag values, then

( 140 * .7 ) = 98 mm

( 160 * .7 ) = 112 mm

So the fork will only be about 1.4 cm longer during normal riding, and at a 68 degree head angle, you will barely notice the difference in height. This assumes
the two forks have roughly equal axle to crown measurements.

If you want an official answer email trek and ask if putting the new fork on will void the frame warranty.

http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/support/contact/

If it were my bike, I'd do it without a second thought. But I love building franken bikes.

Comment: I'm not going to this. It's just a theoretical question, because I never did it, I wondered about how the bike frame are made to be standard

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Never mind :) I was not a question.